# Socket programming over TLS in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tls1.2, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to implement a client that talks to a server using TCP over TLS. I have the server certificate, client certificate and private key.

I am creating an SSLSocketFactory object with the certificates and keys.

```
public static SSLSocketFactory createSSLSocketFactory(Key privateKey,
                                                      Certificate clientKeyCert,
                                                      Certificate serverCertificate) {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        trustStore.load(null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("server-certificate", serverCertificate);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        KeyStore identityStore = createEmptyKeyStore();
        identityStore.setKeyEntry("tls-keypair", privateKey.getEncoded(), new Certificate[]{clientKeyCert});

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(identityStore, null);

        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS);
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("createSSLSocketFactory failed", e).log();
        throw new RuntimeException("createSSLSocketFactory failed", e);
    }
}
```

And then I am creating a socket using the SSLSocketFactory.

```
private SSLSocket getSocket() throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    socket.setSoTimeout(6 * 1000); // N sec
    logger.info("using secure socket").log();
    SSLSocket socket1 = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), socket.getPort(), true);
    logger.info("socket information")
            .attr("enabledCipherSuites", Arrays.toString(socket1.getEnabledCipherSuites()))
            .attr("enabledProtocols", Arrays.toString(socket1.getEnabledProtocols()))
            .attr("supportedCipherSuites", Arrays.toString(socket1.getSupportedCipherSuites()))
            .attr("supportedProtocols", Arrays.toString(socket1.getSupportedProtocols()))
            .log();
    logger.info("starting handshake").log();
    socket1.startHandshake();
    logger.info("completed handshake").log();
    return socket1;
}
```

But the handshake doesn't complete successfully and I get

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

I am using java 8 and TLS 1.2.

Please help.

---

I enabled debug logs for SSL handshake. Handshake is failing with error

```
javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|30|http-nio-9074-exec-2|2022-04-06 13:41:36.297 UTC|TransportContext.java:316|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1300)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1166)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
at in.zeta.harpocrates.api.thales.tls.SSLTestController.send(SSLTestController.java:164)
at in.zeta.harpocrates.api.thales.tls.SSLTestController.testEncryptAndDecrypt(SSLTestController.java:65)
at in.zeta.harpocrates.api.thales.tls.SSLTestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b4377ded.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
at in.zeta.springframework.boot.commons.metrics.AbstractMetricReporter.captureAndReportControllerMetrics(AbstractMetricReporter.java:20)
at in.zeta.springframework.boot.commons.metrics.MetricReporter.captureAndReportControllerMetrics(MetricReporter.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at in.zeta.harpocrates.api.thales.tls.SSLTestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4d05932.testEncryptAndDecrypt(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at in.zeta.springframework.boot.commons.authentication.AuthenticationInterceptor.doFilterInternal(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:27)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.NormalStrategy.doFilter(NormalStrategy.java:38)
at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39)
at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.OpenTelemetryHandlerMappingFilter.doFilter(OpenTelemetryHandlerMappingFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.SecurityStrategy.doFilter(SecurityStrategy.java:33)
at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39)
at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at in.zeta.springframework.boot.commons.network.CachedHttpServletBodyFilter.doFilter(CachedHttpServletBodyFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at in.zeta.springframework.boot.commons.logging.SpectraUtils.lambda$wrapWithSpectraContext$1(SpectraUtils.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:251)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
at sun.security.ssl.Finished$T12FinishedProducer.onProduceFinished(Finished.java:399)
at sun.security.ssl.Finished$T12FinishedProducer.produce(Finished.java:374)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:421)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHelloDone$ServerHelloDoneConsumer.consume(ServerHelloDone.java:182)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291)
... 117 more}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to Trouble shoot **

1. Is the Server is implemented with One way TLS or Two Way TLS as the Approach is slightly different . You can check with Server team who provided you the URL / IP or Port
2. **TLS can be One way or Two -way TLS ( Mutual TLS) **
   Try to Initiate openssl Command if you have linux Environment

   *openssl s_client -msg -debug -status -tls1_2 -connect HOSTIP:HOSTPORT*
3. Check if this working to rule out issue is not there with Handshake
4. You can try this InstallCert java code to rule out issue in Certificate or Host and to keep SSL Certificate in Java TrustStore

[Github installCert code](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert)